# boxplot from row values in a dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice, reshape

I got following data frame (simplified here):

```
    H2475  H2481  H2669  H2843  H2872  H2873  H2881  H2909
E1 24.470 26.481 15.120 18.490 16.189 11.422 14.886 18.512
E2  1.016  0.363  0.509  1.190  1.855  0.958  0.771  0.815
E3  0.671  0.637  0.571  0.447  0.116  0.452  0.403  0.753
E4  3.448  2.826  2.183  2.607  4.288  2.526  2.820  3.523
E5  2.548  1.916  1.126  1.553  1.089  1.228  0.887  1.065
```

where E1 - E5 are row numbers. I would like to create a boxplot (or even better violin plot) for the values of each row. I want to ignore column IDs, and have row IDs as "factors".

Something like this top answer:
[How to generate boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147836/how-to-generate-boxplot)

but with E1 - E5 as values. As you may guess I am new to melt/cast/reshape.

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You had thought through the problem 95% of the way there. You were just missing that you needed to create a column out of the `row.names()`. Something like this should work assuming your data is stored in a data.frame named `dat`

```
library(ggplot2)
dat$group <- row.names(dat)
dat.m <- melt(dat, id.vars = "group")
ggplot(dat.m, aes(group, value)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Although you have already accepted the answer from @Chase, I show you a more simply way:

```
 boxplot(t(dat))
```