# Generate per-month summaries, and single boxplot

Tags: r

I have my data in a space-separated text file; each line represents a data point contained in a given month:

```
Jan/2012 1000
Jan/2012 1500
Jan/2012 1200
Feb/2012 1300
Feb/2012 1400
Feb/2012 1000
...
Dec/2012 1300
Dec/2012 1400
Dec/2012 1000
```

I'd like to generate for each month the min, max, median, mean, standard deviation, and 95th quantile.  I'd also like to generate a boxplot for the entire year.  How can I do this in R?  I can load the data with `mydata = read.table(file="mydata.txt", sep=" ")`, but summary produces output like:

```
      month              time          
 Aug/2012: 229357   Min.   :    31100  
 Oct/2012: 223158   1st Qu.:    91267  
 Mar/2012: 221986   Median :   124048  
 Apr/2012: 215368   Mean   :   199639  
 Jul/2012: 213956   3rd Qu.:   176766  
 May/2012: 200920   Max.   :150018802  
 (Other) :1146616
```

I don't have any experience generating boxplots; guidance is welcome.

Comment: Aggregating / grouping questions are close to the most within the [r] tag. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega) is the canonical question, however you may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758566/how-can-i-use-functions-returning-vectors-like-fivenum-with-ddply-or-aggregate/14804827#14804827) pertinant. A quick search for `[r] boxplot` would get you some [pointers for boxplots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147836/how-to-generate-boxplot).

Comment: especially with dates also please use `dput()` to provide your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tapply(dfrm$time, substr(dfrm$month, 1,3), summary)
library(Hmisc)
tapply(dfrm$time, substr(dfrm$month, 1,3), describe)
boxplot(time~month, data=dfrm)
```